# Looking for a trio of cyberpunkish books about a character named swordfish

Tags: story-identification, cyberpunk

Looking for a trio of cyberpunkish books about a character named swordfish that were written in the 70's or 80's....there was a main female character and some kind of hologram suit.

Comment: Are you positive about the name Swordfish? The vague plotline that you have suggests the Sprawl Trilogy by William Gibson (Neuromancer, Count Zero, and Mona Lisa Overdrive), with the female character Molly Millions.

Comment: Thank you for answering but no...I am very familiar with the Gibson books. This trilogy was also very urban but there was a young female who was involved with this Swordfish character.

Comment: You should formally accept the answer below.

Answer (score 6):

Hah! It's [Wilhelmina Baird](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?492)'s Crashcourse trilogy. The three books are Crashcourse, Clipjoint, and Psykosis. In the first book, Cass (Cassandra Blaine) and her friends Moke and Dosh agree to star in a cyber-movie where viewers can experience their emotions.