# Movie with a character named Swordfish and a “Star Wars cantina”-type scene

Tags: story-identification, movie

There is a movie with a "Star Wars cantina" type scene, and all I can remember is that there was a character named Swordfish.  No, it's not the movie "Swordfish."  It's got to be from the 80's or early 90's.  Can anyone help?

Comment: IMDB comes up with zero results for a character called Swordfish, so possibly you have misremembered the name.  Is there anything else you can remember about the movie?

Comment: Is the answer to [this question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/46031/19561) relevant?

Comment: I tried that too.  Unfortunately I only have that one detail, and Swordfish might not have been a major character.  Wondering if it was a Holadeck scene in an old Star Trek episode??

Comment: Do any of [these 5 movies](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v-bF8AxT12o) seem familiar? [Galaxina](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0080771/), [Starcrash](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0079946/), [Battle Beyond the Stars](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0080421/), [Message From Space](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0078435/), or [Turkish Star Wars](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0182060/)

Answer (score 1):

The **Crashcourse** trilogy [**Crashcourse** (1993), **Clipjoint** (1994), and **Psykosis** (1995)], by Wilhelmina Baird, includes a main character whose street name is "Swordfish". In the first novel there is one scene quite similar to the *Star Wars* cantina. The major difference is that the alien-looking characters in **Crashcourse** are human spacers with "symbionts" (I think that's the word from the novel; don't have it in front of me). If I recall correctly, in the second novel there was another similar scene: this time the bar is in a space habitat.

Both of these bars are rather more ... decadent than the *Star Wars* cantina.

However, I don't see any sign that they were ever made into movies. Sorry.

[***a few minutes later***]

Whoops! Guess I should have followed that link in the earlier Comment.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a long-shot:

Is it [Arena (1989)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0101366/?ref_=fn_al_tt_2)?  When I watched it, there were a couple times I was strongly reminded of the cantina scene from Star Wars.

Per IMDB:

> An intergalactic fighting competition between champions of various
>   worlds has traditionally been won by a species much larger and
>   stronger than humans. Entering the contest, a human finds he has to
>   battle against not just his opponents and his self-doubts, but the
>   corrupt system.

The movie begins with main character Steve Armstrong doing a mediocre job as a diner worker/soda jerk to earn passage off of the planet.  Within the first 20 minutes, he ends up fighting two aliens billed as "**Fish Kids**" when they start causing trouble in the diner, which leads his boss to think that Steve has a chance to be the first human in 50 years with a shot at the fighting championship.

Later, Steve and his boss end up in a bar that looks like the cantina.  The main entertainment for the patrons is a **hologram** of a lovely singer/dancer giving a performance.

Also, it doesn't look (to me) like the IMDB cast list is complete.  I remember a lot more names being flung around than what is on the list, so it is possible that the Swordfish name you want is actually in the movie.

You can probably find clips on YouTube if you search "Arena 1989."